# Spring Integration WireTap Selector doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I create the IntegrationFlows in DSL:

```
return IntegrationFlows
            .from(yieldCurveConversionResultChannel)
            .wireTap(notificationChannel, wt -> wt.selector(m -> (m.getPayload() instanceof Throwable)))
            .get();
```

In the selector of wireTap, I tried to filter the message payload is instance of Exception.

There is also a Flow to handle notification service.

```
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(notificationChannel)
            .handle(commonNotificationService)
            .get();
```

But it seems doesn't work. I could get the message which payload isn't instance of Exception.

Did anyone meet this issue before? Or I get something wrong?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works well:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66813194Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66813194Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("yieldCurveConversionResultChannel")
                .wireTap(notificationChannel(), wt -> wt.selector(m -> (m.getPayload() instanceof Throwable)))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel notificationChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow notification() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(notificationChannel())
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

}
```

---

```
@SpringBootTest
class So66813194ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel yieldCurveConversionResultChannel;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        this.yieldCurveConversionResultChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        this.yieldCurveConversionResultChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>(new RuntimeException()));
    }

}
```

And I see in the console only this:

```
2021-03-26 09:36:25.367  INFO 15164 --- [           main] o.s.i.s.s.So66813194ApplicationTests     : Started So66813194ApplicationTests in 1.229 seconds (JVM running for 2.365)
GenericMessage [payload=java.lang.RuntimeException, headers={id=85633b3f-7a17-6b70-8a34-9cbc5aacbf5b, timestamp=1616765785796}]
2021-03-26 09:36:25.810  INFO 15164 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'yieldCurveConversionResultChannel' channel
```

So, that `foo` message from my tests is really rejected by the selector.

Perhaps your problem that some process sends messages to this `notificationChannel` directly - not via the mentioned `WireTap`...

Comment: Yes, I check with another team member he publish the success message from another gateway, which cause the problem. Thank you so much for the answer!